# How do we use Stereo audio with the AAC codec?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, audio

When rendering out a video in Blender 2.8, 2.81, and 2.82, the audio gets mixed down to mono despite being stereo when previewing, and is also about 200% the volume of the preview.
There are no options for Stereo/Mono in the output settings, all we have are Audio Codec, Bitrate, and Volume. I have the Bitrate set to 384 and the volume set to 1.
So how do I render out stereo audio using the AAC codec?

Comment: Might be worth reporting as a bug in the Blender bug tracker. Audio  is often problematic in Blender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was not with Blender, but with the player I was using to view my videos (JetAudio) which didn't employ the AAC codec correctly. When testing with VLC, the videos and audio work correctly so, in this case, Blender was not at fault.

Comment: Sooo, are you saying that VLC etc were reading the badly implemented AAC correctly?